# How can I build an empty Docker image for testing?

Tags: docker

I am a developer learning about docker perks. In my journey, I wrote some [docker shell scripts](https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/tree/development/scripts) to list, clean, or build containers. My dev experience says it is a good practice to unit-test every new feature. I mean, is it possible to docker build an empty container/image only for the sake of testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build an empty image. Specify this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /
```

Building this will produce an empty image.